# Integration Redmine's API in Java

Tags: java, api, integration, redmine-api

I'm trying to integrate redmine's API, to read the subject from a specific Issue with the Id, but I'm getting a NullPointerException in **issueSubject** even if the JSON response is not empty.

`public String getIssueById(){

```
    String issueId = "38480";
    String endPoint = "http://www.redmine.org/issues/" + issueId + ".json";
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(endPoint);
   String auth = "admin:admin";
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes());
    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
    getRequest.setHeader("Authorization", authHeader);
    getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
        Logger.getLogger(responseString + "valore della response string");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(responseString, JsonObject.class);
        String issueSubject = jsonObject.get("issue").getAsJsonObject().get("subject").getAsString();

        System.out.println("Issue Subject: " + value);
        Logger.getLogger(value + "valore della value string");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        return issueSubject ;
    }
}
```

JSON Response:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEhe6.png)

What could be the problem?